# When initially building spring boot module, sourceFolder is incorrect in my iml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

So I setup my initial spring-boot project:

[image]

Then in IntelliJ, I build the rest-service module, and my structure changes to this:

[image]

Then, if I try to run the project `mvn spring-boot:run` I get an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project rest-service: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property -> [Help 1]
```

So I have to go into my rest-service.iml file, and change this:

```
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
```

To this:

```
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
```

My question is, am I initially setting up the project incorrectly?

Comment: Why don't you use IntellJ to create the Spring boot project?

Comment: Trying to now, keep getting error though: `Error:(5, 47) java: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

Your maven project layout is incorrect. The actual source folder (`com`) should have been under src/main/java folder and not directly under `src` as is the case as per screenshot shared. A proper layout for maven project should look like following -

```
└───maven-project
    ├───pom.xml
    └───src
        ├───main
        │   ├───java
        │   └───resources
        └───test
            ├───java
            └───resources
```

Take a look at [Apache Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-directory-structure) for full details.

You can also use [spring-initializr](https://start.spring.io) to create a skeleton project including all dependencies and then import this project as-is in intellij (or eclipse) and take it up for further development.

Also, on a side note, there should not be any need to change anything directly in intellij .iml files generally. Any need to do that means you are missing something somewhere else, in this case the project layout.